# Bus Seat Reservation code amendment in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I was trying this bus seat reservation code, and found this code somewhere here. I was wondering if you could help me change the result. Instead of 0 the seat entered will be "R".

I'm not familiar to Java.

```
import java.io.*;
public class busseatreservation {

public static void printRow(int[] row) {
     for (int i : row) {
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print("\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

 public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
 BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));   
 int twoDm[][]= new int[5][7];
    int i,j,k=1;
    double ans;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<7;j++) {
            twoDm[i][j]=k;
            k++;
        }
    }

    for(int[] row : twoDm) {
        printRow(row);
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
        System.out.print("Enter a Seat number to reserve: ");
        ans = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        k = 1;
        for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<7;j++) {
                if (k == ans) {
                    if (twoDm[i][j]== 0) {
                        System.out.println("That seat has already been reserved");
                    }
                    else {
                         twoDm[i][j]= 0;
                    }
                }
                k++;
            }
        }
        for(int[] row : twoDm) {
            printRow(row);
        }
   }

}
}
```

Comment: The only method in your code is main which has no return value. You will have to be more specific about which result you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you held your elements in integer array. So It is not possible to have an element 'R' of this array. To write 'R', you should hold your elements in a string array. You should use numbers as strings. With this method, both letters and numbers can be element of your array.

Another solution, which is not good, if the corresponding element is 0 you can print R.

Another point is; if user enter a reserved seat, your program gives warning just for 5 times. You should check it out.

Good evening.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please show the it by code?